# How do I add a border to the bottom of my footer widget

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In the past my footer has been colored in thus no bottom border is needed.

However, I've edited the color scheme on my new site which now means the footer is colored white.

I'd like to add a thin black border to the top and bottom.

I know I'm supposed to put all the code in this message but there's literally so much it goes beyond the realm of this Stackoverflow message.

You really have to see it:

Original site (with navy footer section)

```
www.sweetfe.co.uk
```

New site with footer styled white (I want to add a thin black border to the top and bottom where the first sites navy footer ends)

```
http://79.170.44.76/oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/
```

Basically I want my site to look like this:
    http://www.reading-college.ac.uk/sites/default/files/idea.jpg

Please advise,

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: post code, cant understand what boreder you dont know to add. border-bottom

Comment: Please share the image of what is expected.

Comment: Thanks, please see idea at:
    http://www.reading-college.ac.uk/sites/default/files/idea.jpg

Comment: If I understand you well, try `.footer-widget-container { border-top: 1px solid #000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000 }`

Comment: I already see a border where your article starts. Just add a top-border to the footer to mark the articles end...if that is what you meant...

Comment: You hero @mdesdev it worked :D ! No, I just have to workout how to remove the dotted line in my footer! Load up it as an answer and I can award you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well, try

```
.footer-widget-container {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

and about removing dotted border try to remove below line from `style.css`

```
abbr[title] { border-bottom: 1px dotted; }
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatley the dotted border didn't remove, so I put the css line back in. Perhaps it's styled elsewhere.

Comment: Just find it somewhere in the CSS `1px dotted` and remove it ;)